# issue on image saving in samsung devices in custom camera

Tags: android, camera

I am developing android app which use custom camera and my camera orientation is portrait but image is save on landscape and images scratches and accept samsung all device working properly, please give me any solution thanks in advance.
here is my setting camera orientation method.

```
    public void updateCameraRotation(){
            try {
                Camera.CameraInfo info = new Camera.CameraInfo();
                Camera.getCameraInfo(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK, info);
                int rotation = this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
                int degrees = 0;
                switch (rotation) {
                case Surface.ROTATION_0: degrees = 0; break; //Natural orientation
                case Surface.ROTATION_90: degrees = 90; break; //Landscape left
                case Surface.ROTATION_180: degrees = 180; break;//Upside down
                case Surface.ROTATION_270: degrees = 270; break;//Landscape right
                }
                int rotate = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
                Camera.Parameters params = myCamera.getParameters();
                params.setRotation(rotate); 
                myCamera.setParameters(params);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem with this code:

```
deviceName=Util.getInstance().getDeviceName();
if(deviceName.contains("Samsung")||deviceName.equalsIgnoreCase("Samsung")){
    if (bitmap.getWidth() > bitmap.getHeight()) {
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(90);
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    }
}
```